# Join two arrays in Logic Apps

Tags: arrays, function, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I have two variables as Arrays in Logic app
Ex;

```
 Variable A=["A","B"]
    Variable B=["C","D"]
```

I want to combine both and return

```
 Variable 9=["A","B","C","D"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [union function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#union) to combine two arrays:

```
union(variables('arr1'), variables('arr2'))
```

**EDIT** - add version to retain duplicates:

This will produce an array that removes duplicate entries. To retain the duplicates, use the [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#join) function to convert the arrays to strings:

```
join(variables('arr1'),',')
```

Next use [concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#concat) to create a single string:

```
concat(variables('arr1String'),',',variables('arr2String'))
```

Finally, use [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#split) to convert the concatenated string to an array:

```
split(variables('arrStringsConcat'),',')
```

It gets pretty messy, but all together as a single statement:

```
split(concat(join(variables('arr1'),','),',',join(variables('arr2'),',')),',')
```

Comment: the union function removes duplicates, if I have same values in both the arrays how can it be done?

Comment: I updated my answer with a version that retains duplicates.

Comment: Thanks will try this :)